# Caching ml model in flask

Tags: python, api, flask, machine-learning, caching

I have created an API with flask. Everytime the API is called, it need to load the model bin file, load it into an object (im using ctranslate2) then the object is used to translate what ever required to be translated.

This flow is working fine. My problem is that I have many models and the loading time is long as the bin file weight is 200MB (each model).

To improve performance, I want to cache the object return by ctranslate2 from the bin file.

What I have tried:

- flask cache
- Redis

Both of these failed because the ctranslate2 object is not serializable and can't be picked.

I have considered building manually a global dictionary with the object in there and handle suppression and addition of models.

My problem with this solution is it will not work if I do multi thread.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If I am not making a mistake, a caching mechanism is introduced in ctranslate docs. It looks like it supports multithreading as well.

https://github.com/OpenNMT/CTranslate2/blob/master/docs/performance.md

edit: no its more like the page explains how the caching mechanism of NVIDIA can be used with ctranslate2